# Detect Hold Mouse-Click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here is my code:

```
var mouseDown = false;

document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
  console.log("MOUSE DOWN");
  mouseDown = true;
  increaseRad();
}
document.body.onmouseup = function() {
  console.log("MOUSE UP");
  mouseDown = false;
}

function increaseRad(){
  rad = 0;
  while(mouseDown){
    console.log("mouse is still down");
    rad++;
    console.log(rad)
  }
}
```

When I press down, `increaseRad` is run, but the while loop inside never ends.

Any idea why?

Comment: I believe your issue here is that you are incrementing and decrementing the value for your `mousedown` instead of just simply setting it to true/false, then check if that helps.

Comment: No, this makes no difference. I figured the `onmousedown` runs the function asynchronously so the value is set to `true` and if statement is run. But it doesnt seem to woek

Comment: The thing here is that your check to see if the mouse is actually down seems to be called once, this should be in a function of its own to track when you have entered your mouse and when you have left it. This function would then need to be called in your `onmousedown`.

Comment: That makes total sense!! See my edit.. it goes into an infinite while loop

Comment: Right now to break that loop what you gotta do is declare the `mouseDown` as a global scope variable like you did previously. Then when your `onmouseup` is triggered it should set that global variable to false and break out of the loop. Also make an extra function and put your while loop in it, just to avoid the other event not being called because you are currently still in the other.

Comment: The `mouseDown` variable is a global scope variable. But `mouseDown` won't set to `false` when I release the click. Any idea why?

Comment: Do you still get the console log of "MOUSE UP" when releasing the click of the mouse?

Comment: Nope. It goes into an infinite loop. It doesn't detect the "MOUSE UP". I tried putting the while loop in a separate function. No luck. Thanks for all the help btw.

Comment: Hey Greg, how about creating a `setInterval` that checks if you're currently in drawing mode instead of using your while loop? :) And it's okay, that's what we are here for to help until it's solved!

Comment: Hmm... how exactly would you implement that? I'm still curious why the `onmouseup` listener is not calling the function. Other listeners should not be rendered inactive just because another function is being run, right?

Comment: I've updated the question to the specific problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that your code runs as a blocking loop.

```
while(mouseDown){
  console.log("mouse is still down");
  rad++;
  console.log(rad)
}
```

The browser evaluates Javascript in a single thread and this loop will never pause to let the browser process those event handlers.

Instead you can use just use asynchronous functions to listen for mousedown events, then start a timer. If the mouse is still down when the timer finishes, then you can count it as a long click.

```
var mouseIsDown = false;

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  mouseIsDown = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(mouseIsDown) {
      // mouse was held down for > 2 seconds
    }
  }, 2000);
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  mouseIsDown = false;
});
```

These asynchronous actions (`addEventListener`, `setTimeout`) won't block the main thread.

Comment: In this example it can spot mousedown hold only at the very end `mouseup`. With a callback with a `setTimeout` in the `mousedown` function it could spot it earlier on and perform some action based on that. doesn't need a code change, just wanted to point that in case the OP is looking to notify the user in case of hold.

Comment: See, what I want is for an integer to increment, say for every 10 milliseconds. The longer I hold down the mouse, the greater the integer will become. There should not be a limit

Comment: Increment the integer inside the callback to `setTimeout` and if the mouse is   down, start the timeout again recursively.

Comment: Wow. Is this the easiest approach. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Oh, that was easy!! Thanks a mill!

Answer (score 2):

If you click serveral times in a row, you get a wrong click & hold. Better solution is...

```
var mouseIsDown = false;
var idTimeout;

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  mouseIsDown = true;
  idTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    if(mouseIsDown) {
      // mouse was held down for > 2 seconds
    }
  }, 2000);
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  clearTimeout(idTimeout);
  mouseIsDown = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    // press and hold logic
    console.log('Press and hold event detected (non-touch)');
  }, 500);
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```